# Union of object types

Tags: typescript

Why does this not error:

```
interface Man {
  name: string
}

interface Dog {
  breed: string
}

type manDog = Man | Dog;


let x:manDog = {name:"test", breed:"9" }
```

`{name:"test", breed:"9" }` is neither `Man` nor a `Dog`, isn't it?
and `manDog` should be either `Man` or `Dog`, isn't it?
I read about structural typing but still don't understand why it doesn't error.
Can someone explain in a beginner friendly way?

Comment: @TobiasS. I was trying to say I don't understand how the solution in the accepted answer `type T =  {A: number, B: number} | {C: number, A?: undefined, B?: undefined };` worked

Comment: No, a `mandog` can have every property, a `man` or a `dog` has ... But it's only guaranteed to have a certain property if both, `man` and `dog` have this property. So accessing `x.name` will give you an error

Comment: `manDog` is *both* a `Man` *and* a `Dog`... that is, a `Man & Dog`.  And unions are inclusive, so `Man & Dog` is assignable to `Man | Dog`.  See the answers to the linked questions for more information.